# c++ constructor default parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, constructor, default-value

How can I write a constructor specifying default parameters values,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct foo
{
    char *_p;
    int   _q;

    foo( char *p = nullptr, int q = 0 ): _p(p), _q(q)
    {
        cout << "_q: " << _q << endl;
    }
};
```

and then use it passing only some values without taking into account their order ?

E.g.: this works:

```
char tmp;
foo f( &tmp );
```

but this doesn't:

```
foo f( 1 );

$ g++ -O0 -g -Wall -std=c++0x -o test test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:18:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:10:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘foo::foo(char*, int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you can't ignore the order.

However, you can create more than one constructor.

```
struct foo
{
    char *_p;
    int   _q;

    foo( char *p, int q): _p(p), _q(q) {}
    foo( char *p): _p(p), _q(0) {}
    foo( int q): _p(nullptr), _q(q) {}
};
```

### Edit:

By the way, it isn't alway's a good idea to make the order variadic/ignorable. This can sometimes lead to ambiguity or unexpected behavior which is hard to find/debug. In my example calling with `NULL` parameter leads to ambiguity like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fd80df91bd2b33f):

```
class foo {
public:
    foo(int x, unsigned char y=0) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
    foo(unsigned char x, int y=0) : x_(y), y_(x) {}

    int  x_;
    char y_;
};
```

Just as a hint, use clearly defined constuctors/ function overloads instead.

Comment: In his example, a caller using `NULL` could cause problems, so I wouldn't say it is OK.

Comment: Also not a good idea to allow interchanging the order because this leads to a combinatorial explosion of constructors under maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Named Parameter Idiom. It allows to pass parameters in any order by specifying their names. It also allows to leave some parameters with default values and set only chosen ones in a single statement. Usage example:

```
File f = OpenFile("foo.txt")
       .readonly()
       .createIfNotExist()
       .appendWhenWriting()
       .blockSize(1024)
       .unbuffered()
       .exclusiveAccess();
```

Idiom description and `File` implementation details are available at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html

Comment: Just perfect, most elegant solution by far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in C++ to ignore he parameter order.  Still, you can just use function overloading and delegating constructors:

```
struct foo {
    char *_p;
    int   _q;
    // this is the default constructor and can also be used for conversion
    foo( char *p = nullptr, int q = 0 ): _p(p), _q(q)
    {
        cout << "_q: " << _q << endl;
    }
    // this constructor canbe used for conversion.
    foo( int q, char *p = nullptr): foo(p, q) {}
};
```

Also, consider adding `explicit` to avoid use of the constructors for implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Order is necessary, based on the order and data type function overloading is working...
you can overload the function to achieve you need, like

```
struct foo
{
    char *_p;
    int   _q;

    foo( char *p, int q): _p(p), _q(q) {}
    foo( int q, char *p): _p(p), _q(q) {}
    foo( char *p):foo(p,0)
    {  
    }
    foo( int q):foo(q,nullptr)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: This does not compile :D but, with a few changes it would work in C++11: `foo(char* p): foo(p, 0) {}` and `foo(int q): foo(q, nullptr) {}`

Comment: Thank you Massa for pointing out my mistake... i will edit my post

Comment: @Massa, that previous version of code was compiling fine in `gcc version 4.8.2` , still i have changed as per you suggestion because i fell this is the standard way to do.